# What's the name of algorithm to decide best collect frequency in facebook games?

Tags: facebook, knapsack-problem

So in many facebook games there are various buildings with different collect frequency and the number of collection you can make depends on the length and gap of periods of free time you have in a day.

Thinking about how to find the maximum occurrence of different frequency reminds me of words like knapsack and scheduling, but I forgot what's really the name of the algorithm about this or whether this is as difficult as those problems.

So, what's the name I am looking for?

Thanks.

(Test: Is it possible to bump a question in SO?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like weighted [interval scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling).

> A list of tasks is given as a set of time intervals; for instance, one task might run from 2:00 to 5:00 and another task might run from 6:00 to 8:00. Posed as an optimization problem, the goal is to maximize the number of executed tasks without overlapping the tasks. A request corresponds to an interval of time. We say that a subset of requests is compatible if no two of them overlap in time and our goal is to accept as large a compatible subset as possible. A compatible set of maximum size is called optimal.